# VS2010 Building Installer Failing on Setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have created an application in C# visual studio 2010.

The application works fine in debug mode and builds successfully.  The application has three aspects to the solution.  When i build and deploy the setup file i get an error on the install as soon as i click install in the steps.

The error says Installation Incomplete, The installer was interuppted before InvoiceProcess could be installed.  You need to restart the installer to try again.

When i restart i get the same error.

Both the development machine and machine to deploy on are both 64 bit windows 10.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons that it is not getting installed because **IIS6 management compatibility is not configured on IIS**.

**Visual Studio 2010** installer still targets the older version of IIS (means IIS6) although IIS7 was publicly available in 2008. That’s why IIS6 compatibility is required.

Comment: I have done some research on this and it does not appear to be the problem.